# iOS - How can I use a common view to draw different views depending on a property?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiview, subclass

I have 2 views named 'AA' and 'AB' (and in a near future I'll have more: 'AC', 'AD', etc...).
Right now in my viewControllers, I need to import all my UIView subclass and test something in order to know which subview I need to create and add to the view hierarchy.

My idea was to create a view named 'A' which will figure out which subviews it needs to draw and 'change' it's class to a private one which could be 'AA' or 'AB'.
But I don't know how to do it.

Of course, I could test what needs to be tested and then add the new view as a subview but the idea was to have only one view and not a view within a view.

Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a variation of the [*State Design Pattern*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern) to implement a system where an object needs to configure its activities at run time. Rather than creating views within a view, you could create a single view that keeps a list of things that know how to draw in a view without themselves being `UIView` objects.

Here is an example:

```
@interface ViewDraw
-(void)drawInView; // the UIView caller can pass parameters here
@end
@interface ViewDrawA : ViewDraw
-(void)drawInView;
@end
@interface ViewDrawB : ViewDraw
-(void)drawInView;
@end
@interface ViewDrawC : ViewDraw
-(void)drawInView;
@end
```

Now your `ViewA` class can keep an `NSArray` of `ViewDraw` objects, configure it with the view draw objects that it needs to draw, and then call upon them to do the drawing. Reconfiguring the list of `ViewDraw` objects will have the effect of `ViewA` changing its behavior at run time.

Comment: and ViewDraw is a subclass of NSObject or UIView ?

Comment: @Dave It's a subclass of `NSObject`.

Comment: I may be wrong but a nsobject isn't supposed to draw. Usually UIViews or subclasses  are supposed to to draw no ?

Comment: @Dave Anything can help `UIView` draw. `UIView` has the `drawRect` method, which may call methods of other objects to perform the drawing. As long as it's `drawRect` that makes the call, it's `UIView` that does the drawing as far as the iOS is concerned.